# AWS DMS not able to migrate some tables between MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms, rdbms

I am migrating AWS RDS MySQL instance to another AWS RDS MySQL instance using Data migration service (DMS). Found below tables in mysql and performance_schema databases are not migrating and giving an error with `pending validation` in DMS table statistics.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Schema Name            |   Table              | Load State
----------------------------------------------------------
Performance_schema       session_variables    Table error
Performance_schema       global_status        Table error
Performance_schema       global_variables     Table error
Performance_schema       session_status       Table error
mysql                    event                Table error
mysql                    user                 Table error
mysql                    proc                 Table error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the diagnosis with  AWS CLI command `aws dms  describe-table-statistics --replication-task-arn arn:<<your replication task arn>>`

Also, for more details, please refer Troubleshoot an AWS DMS task validation failure [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-task-validation-failed-stuck/)

Comment: describe-table-statistics output can be viewed in DMS - table statistics, that where i got the above output. DMS didnt create the awsdms_validation_failures_v1 table because the tables not went to ValidationSuspended or the ValidationFailed state.